# Please help! I accidentally deleted left nav so I can't find my pages

Tags: 2013

Boneheaded move on my part, I thought I was deleting left nav links for just the one sub-site, but it was for the entire library. Now I can't figure out how to get back to Pages library. Need to get the Conversations, Notebook, Pages, etc. links back.

Answer (score 5):

Hit the gear icon (upper right-hand corner) and select Site Contents. This will take you to a page where you can see your libraries (including the Pages library).

And to get it back on the left nave, go to the library, click on Library Settings on the ribbon, and then "List name, description and navigation" (first link on the settings page). Under display this document library on the quick launch, select yes and save.